# How to convert Openweathermap icon code to actual image

Tags: java, android, icons, openweathermap

i need help converting OpenWeatherMap icon into the actual png image.

So far, i retrieved the icon code (iconName) into the text view, as well as created String for the full image url (iconUrl).

```
String iconName = JSONWeather.getString("icon");
String iconUrl = JSONWeather.getString(IMG_URL + iconName +".png");
```

But i struggle to insert this url into the image view.

The error i receive is

**E/Utils: Problem parsing the earthquake JSON results
    org.json.JSONException: No value for https://openweathermap.org/img/w/04n.png**

I saw Picasso could be used here, but below code shows viewHolder on red for me, and i don't know what need to be added to resolve this.

```
Picasso.with(viewHolder.itemView.getContext()).load(iconUrl).into(viewHolder.condIcon)



<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/condIcon"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       />


   ImageView iconView =  findViewById(R.id.condIcon);
        iconView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(earthquake.iconUrl));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved!
To mention, my app consists of 3 classes: Utils, MainActivity and Event.

First of all, in Utils.java **parse your JSON icon:**

```
 /**URL for the icons location at OpenWeatherMap*/
    public static final String IMG_URL = "https://openweathermap.org/img/w/";

 //Retrieve icon code from website
                String iconName = JSONWeather.getString("icon");
```

Secondly, in Event. java add:

**at the top**

```
public final String iconName;
```

**and class**

```
 public Event(.....String eventIconName)
{ .......
     iconName=eventIconName;
      }
```

Thirdly, in MainActivity.java **add image view and picasso reference**:

```
//Convert icon code from the OpenWeatherMap website into the image and insert into the ImageView. Path consists of URL declared in Utils.java, and @param iconName, declared in Event.java.
// JSON parser method used in Utils.java class retrieves icon code from OpenWeatherMap (iconName), .png extension is added.

    ImageView iconView =  findViewById(R.id.condIcon);
    Picasso.with(this).load(IMG_URL + weather.iconName +".png").into(iconView);
```

Frankly speaking, I spent 2 days figuring this out. Hopefully, this will be helpful for other people.

Comment: Now I have new problem - how to increase the icon size :P

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way, but still following similar format:

```
.then(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      var currentIconDay0 = data.weather[0].icon;
      var weatherIconDay0 = document.getElementById('weatherIconDay0');
      var img0 = document.createElement("img");
      img0.src = 'https://openweathermap.org/img/w/' + currentIconDay0 + '.png'
                weatherIconDay0.appendChild(img0);
```